# "Multi-Object editing not supported" when trying to make an Editor Script to show and edit 3d arrays in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

So I tried implementing a script for showing and editing 3D arrays in the editor. Over the ClickableLogic Script, which inherits the variable I want to display, it says "Multi-Object editing not supported". I've never done anything with editor scripts before, and I was wondering if anyone here could help me out with this issue.

So here's the code:

```
[CustomEditor(typeof(ClickableLogic))]
[CanEditMultipleObjects]
public class RenderThreeDimensionalArray : Editor
{
    public override void OnInspectorGUI()
    {
        ClickableLogic script = (ClickableLogic)target;

        EditorGUI.BeginChangeCheck();

        for (int i = 0; i < script.DialogueNumber.GetLength(0); i++)
        {
            EditorGUILayout.LabelField("Layer " + i);

            for (int j = 0; j < script.DialogueNumber.GetLength(1); j++)
            {
                EditorGUILayout.BeginHorizontal();

                for (int k = 0; k < script.DialogueNumber.GetLength(2); k++)
                {
                    script.DialogueNumber[i, j, k] = EditorGUILayout.IntField(script.DialogueNumber[i, j, k]);
                }

                EditorGUILayout.EndHorizontal();
            }
        }

        if (EditorGUI.EndChangeCheck())
        {
            EditorUtility.SetDirty(script);
        }
    }
}
```

As said earlier, the problem is that it says that multi-object editing is not supported.